# Get all Messages in a RabbitMQ queue as csv or excel

Tags: excel, csv, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have around 10000 messages in my RabbitMq queue in ready state. I am thinking of purging the messages but before purging I need to get all the message details downloaded as a csv or excel for backup purpose.

Is there a way to do this. I am using RabbitMQ management plugin (Web UI).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't export the messages for the web-management as csv/excel.

You can consume it, and save the messages as you prefer